# Ubuntu 22.04: Window not interacting with mouse and desktop icons shining through after screen look

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I have a problem with program windows that stop interacting with the mouse and render problems after screenlock with the GNOME desktop (current Ubuntu 22.04).

The problem is reproducible as follows:

1. Window is in focus
2. Lock screen (Windows key+L or wait some minutes until auto-screenlock)
3. Unlock screen with password

   Now the previous window does not interact with the mouse and the desktop icons shine through.
   In the case of VLC, even the video and sound continues to play, but since the window is no longer active, I can no longer use the mouse to operate the video buttons. But the spacebar still causes playback to pause.

When I click on the respective window in the bar on the left, the window is rendered normally again (without desktop icons shining through) and I can interact with the window normally with the mouse again.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the make/model of the computer (laptop?) that you're running as this will help in troubleshooting this issue. Also, did you recently do anything that may have caused this behavior, or was this always how your install of the Ubuntu OS worked? Thanks